# It doesn't work AS WHAT THEY SAY IT IS (phrase/expression)

Tags: expressions, phrases

Let's say you have downloaded an '**adblocker**' app on your phone. Then, when you are testing it, it's not *working*, you are now grumpy due to that because you feel that you have been fooled by the *app's description* that it will work. You say:

> "It doesn't work **as what they say it is!"**

Is this the correct phrase/expression in English?

Answer (score 1):

No, it is not correct for quite a few reasons.  Foremost, there should be a verb after **they**. Second, **work** (in the sense of 'to function') is a DO-verb not an IS-verb, so **is** should be **does** or **should | would (work)**.  Finally, **what** is incorrect with **work**.

work how ...

do what ...

Possible correct phrases:

> It doesn't work how they say it does.
>
> It doesn't work as they say (it does).
>
> It doesn't work how they said it would.
>
> It isn't working as they said it would.
>
> It doesn't work as they said it would.

You could substitute **should** for **would**.

There are other ways as well, using **DO**:

> It doesn't do what they say (it does).
>
> It doesn't do what they say it should.

The phrases in parentheses can be omitted.

Comment: Hello, can you say this: "**It doesn't work the way they said"**?

Comment: Yes, that is good. "the way they said" is another form of "as they said" or "how they said".

Comment: Hope you don't mind, I just want to make this expression as clear as day according to what I am really trying to say (you know that feeling when you can't spell it out, kinda it's on the tip of your tongue?). This is the last: "**It's not functioning similar to what they said from their description"** how about it now?

Comment: That is rather verbose.  "similar to what" could be reduced to "as". "from" should be "in".   *It's not working as the description says it does.*

Comment: Hello, let's this is the improved phrasing compared to the previous entries. How about this: **"it's not working the same as described"** -avoiding verbosity yet effective-